# Need an expert for advanced internet radio solution

Tags: streaming, flash, audio, internet

Long story short - online radio with both admin and client interfaces in flash (it will be browser based radio).

I cant figure out the best way to mix live audio stream from microphone with uploaded media files (e.g. mp3). I have considered Red5, FMS and Wowza as possible server solutions for this, but have no idea how to make it work together.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldnt this be on stackoverflow ?

Comment: No.  This belongs here.  The bulk of the question is about the serverside software.

Comment: You don't say what you have tried to make the products you mentioned work together, and at the moment your question is effectively "I can't be bothered with this, do it for me". You might consider editing your question to include some of the steps you've taken so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been helpful if you'd mentioned any constraints regarding operating systems / budget.

[Jack](http://jackaudio.org/) might be useful for the mixing, [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) provides (basic) mixing and a streaming server (and can integrate with Jack)

Comment: I would prefer unix environment but in general there are no limitations about operating system. Budget is also theoretically unlimited (anyway the price of software must be reasonable).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [liquidsoap](http://savonet.sourceforge.net).

It can schedule multiple input streams and create file-based streams from an mp3 playlist.  You could use a simple flash player like [ffmp3](http://ffmp3.sourceforge.net/)

A flash-bashed admin interface is not available for liquidsoap.